# Deserialize error with jackson json in case of list in java

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have create a JSON with Jackson based on this class:

```
    public class One {
    public long param;

    public List<Two> two;

    public static class Two{
        public long param;
        public List<Short> param2;
    }
}
```

I have defined two constructor for each class and I use it for the creation of the objects that later are written on the json file. The outcome is (valid JSON):

```
[{"param":1,"Two":[{"param":4,"param2":[1,2,3]},{"param":5,"parma2":[4,5,6]}]},{"param":2,"Two":[{"param":6,"param2":[1,2,3]}]}]
```

Now I would like to read and load the parameters and I define:

```
    mapper.configure(Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true); //tried with and without
    JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser jp;
jp = f.createJsonParser(FILE);
    jp.nextToken();
    while (jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
         mapper.readValue(jp, One.class);
     }
     jp.close();
```

I have this error:

```
Can not deserialize instance of json.One$Two out of START_ARRAY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Load of the json file:

```
List<One> myObjects = new ArrayList<One>();
myObjects = mapper.readValue(FILE, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, One.class));
```

The code in the class is edited by adding only `@JsonProperty("Two")`:

```
   public class One {
    public long param;
    @JsonProperty("Two")
    public List<Two> two;

    public static class Two{
        public long param;
        public List<Short> param2;
    }
}
```